# jqgrid custom formatter button click event not working

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter

I have constructed a jqgrid dynamically, i am unable to invoke the function onclick of the button.

My Code:

```
function buildButtons(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
            var optionsRowId = options.rowId;
            var editDelButtons = "<input style=\"height:22px;width:40px;\" type=\"button\" value=\"Edit\" onclick=\"javascript:testRow('" + optionsRowId + "')\" />";
            return editDelButtons;

        }

function testRow(rowID)
{
  alert(rowID);
 }
```

}

The error i get always when i click on the buton in each row of jqgrid is "function is not defined"

My function is written right below the customFormatter function.

Please help me ASAP, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a larger code example (EG: jsfiddle) that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the `testRow` function out of the `.ready()` function.

e.g.

```
$(function(){

    function buildButtons(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        var optionsRowId = options.rowId;
        var editDelButtons = "<input style=\"height:22px;width:40px;\" type=\"button\" value=\"Edit\" onclick=\"javascript:testRow('" + optionsRowId + "')\" />";

        return editDelButtons;
    }

})

function testRow(rowID)
{
    alert(rowID);
}
```