# Get current row value into a jQuery event handler without looping

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I know how to use a custom formatter and call a JavaScript function in `jqGrid`. I also know that I can use gridComplete function to bind a jQuery event. My question is similar to the following – but not the same.
[Custom formatter in jqGrid which calls jQuery function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590560/custom-formatter-in-jqgrid-which-calls-jquery-function)

Okay, in the approach mentioned in the above question, we can use a jQuery function on the click event of the element returned by the formatter – but it required looping through all the rows.

Is there a better way to get the current row value into a `jQuery event handler` without **looping**, in `jqGrid`?

Note: Please note that I need to invoke a `jQuery event handler` which will process current row value – not a simple javascript function.

My code is listed below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clickme(rowID) {
        alert("hi");
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#grid").jqGrid({
            url: "GamesList.aspx/GetMyGames",
            mtype: 'POST',
            postData: {
                gameSearch: $('#txtGameName').val(),
                ownerSearch: $('#txtOwner').val(),
                createdDateFrom: $('#txtCreatedFrom').val(),
                createdDateTo: $('#txtCreatedTo').val(),
                liquidAmountFrom: $('#txtLmiquidAmountFrom').val(),
                liquidAmountTo: $('#txtLmiquidAmountTo').val()
            },
            datatype: "local", //json if want to load initially
            ajaxGridOptions: {
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            },
            serializeGridData: function(postData) {
                return JSON.stringify(postData);
            },
            jsonReader: {
                repeatitems: false,
                root: function(obj) {
                    return obj.d;
                }
            },
            colNames: ['GameID', 'GameName', 'GameOwner', 'PlannedCloseDate', 'CreatedOnDate', 'GameLiquidAmount', 'Join'],
            colModel: [{
                name: 'GameID',
                index: 'GameID'
            }, {
                name: 'GameName',
                index: 'GameName'
            }, {
                name: 'GameOwner',
                index: 'GameOwner'
            }, {
                name: 'PlannedCloseDate',
                index: 'PlannedCloseDate',
                formatter: 'date',
                formatoptions: {
                    srcformat: 'm/d/Y',
                    newformat: 'm/d/Y'
                }
            }, {
                name: 'CreatedOnDate',
                index: 'CreatedOnDate',
                formatter: 'date',
                formatoptions: {
                    srcformat: 'm/d/Y',
                    newformat: 'm/d/Y'
                }
            }, {
                name: 'GameLiquidAmount',
                index: 'GameLiquidAmount'
            }, {
                name: 'Join',
                index: 'GameID',
                width: 30,
                formatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                    return '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-folder-open app-custom-button-join"  title="click to open" onclick="clickme(' + options.rowId + ') ;"></span>';
                }
            }],
            rowNum: 10,
            /*rowList: [10, 20, 30],*/
            pager: '#pager2',
            sortname: 'id',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            caption: "Games",
            gridview: true,
            height: "auto",
            loadonce: true,
            recordtext: "Records {0} - {1} of {2}",
            emptyrecords: "No records to view",
            loadtext: "Loading...",
            pgtext: "Page {0} of {1}",
            gridComplete: function() {
                //Assign a click event to custom button [after gridComplete]
                $(".app-custom-button-join").click(function() {
                    alert("HELLO");
                });
            }
        });
        $("#btnSearch").click(function(e) {
            $("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam', {
                datatype: 'json'
            }).trigger('reloadGrid');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

**References:**

1. [jqgrid custom formatter button click event not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704774/jqgrid-custom-formatter-button-click-event-not-working)
2. [jqGrid gridComplete:- getRowData - get row cell value from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285282/jqgrid-gridcomplete-getrowdata-get-row-cell-value-from-array)
3. [Issue with jqGrid and jquery click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839585/issue-with-jqgrid-and-jquery-click-event)
4. [Custom formatter in jqGrid which calls jQuery function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590560/custom-formatter-in-jqgrid-which-calls-jquery-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. Your current code bind **separate** (*multiple*) `click` handler for every `span.app-custom-button-join` of the column `Join`. To make the code more effective one can register **one** `click` handler on the whole grid. The standard event processing makes bubbling (from inner to outer). jqGrid registers already one `click` handler and it has `beforeSelectRow` and `onCellSelect` which will be called inside of the `click` handler. Thus you can replace `gridComplete` with more effective code of `beforeSelectRow` callback for example. The corresponding implementation can looks like below

```
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    var $self = $(this),
        $td = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow>td"),
        rowid = $td.parent().attr("id"),
        rowData = $self.jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid),
        // or rowData = $self.jqGrid("getRowData", rowid)
        iCol = $td.length > 0 ? $td[0].cellIndex : -1,
        colModel = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
    if (iCol >= 0 && colModel[iCol].name === "Join" &&
            $(e.target).hasClass("app-custom-button-join")) {
        alert("HELLO");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The above code shows how to get `rowid` of clicked row. The Boolean value returned from `beforeSelectRow` allows you to deny selection of row by click on the icon (if it's required of cause). One need just return `false` from `beforeSelectRow` to prevent selection.

Comment: Thanks.. How can we alert value of current row's GameName alomg with "HELLO"?

Comment: @Lijo: You use `loadonce: true`. So the data returned from the server will be saved locally in `data`. You can use `var rowData = $self.jqGrid("getRowData", rowid);`  to get the row data by `rowid`. It's the reference to the original item of data which saves jqGrid internally. So `rowData.GameName` is the non-formatted content of `GameName` returned from the server. Alternatively you can get it from the cell of jqGrid an unformat it. It's more slow, but you can use it too (especially if  `loadonce: false`): `var gameName = $self.jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "GameName");`

Comment: Thanks, it worked... It would be good if you can edit your answer with the above comment so that the answer will be more complete.

Comment: @Lijo: You are welcome! I did the modifications. I have to mention that my previous comment have copy/pased error. It's more effective to use `getLocalRow` in case of `loadonce: true`, but one can use `getRowData` or `getCell` is `loadonce: false`. By the way: Do you tried [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31647535/315935)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not too sure about efficiency of the solution, but you can make the data in the rows have an event handler like:

```
$(document).on("click", "#id", function(){});
```

Then you can use `$(this).val();` to find the value of the element.

Does that answer your question???